# Resizing images to specific pixel width and height in Automator

Tags: macos, automator

I've been searching for about an hour now to try and find a way to do this.

Is there any way in Automator to resize images to a specified width and height, instead of just the longest size? I need my output images to be a specific pixel width and height, even if it is disproportionate.

I have photoshop, so is there a way to get Automator to do this?

Thanks

Comment: How about: http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_batchresize_images_automator

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no way to do what you need with a standard Automator step.

Anyway, you can use [this](https://gist.github.com/riccardomarotti/4737373) Python script:

```py
import sys
import CoreGraphics

RESIZE_WIDTH = 100
RESIZE_HEIGHT = 100

def resizeimage(source_image_file, target_image_file, target_width, target_height):
    source_image = CoreGraphics.CGImageImport(CoreGraphics.CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(source_image_file))

    source_width = source_image.getWidth()
    source_height = source_image.getHeight()

    source_image_rect = CoreGraphics.CGRectMake(0, 0, source_width, source_height)
    new_image = source_image.createWithImageInRect(source_image_rect)

    colors_space = CoreGraphics.CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    colors = CoreGraphics.CGFloatArray(5)
    context = CoreGraphics.CGBitmapContextCreateWithColor(target_width, target_height, colors_space, colors)
    context.setInterpolationQuality(CoreGraphics.kCGInterpolationHigh)
    new_image_rect = CoreGraphics.CGRectMake(0, 0, target_width, target_height)
    context.drawImage(new_image_rect, new_image)
    context.writeToFile(target_image_file, CoreGraphics.kCGImageFormatJPEG)



def main(argv):
    for image_file_name in argv:
        resizeimage(image_file_name, image_file_name, RESIZE_WIDTH, RESIZE_HEIGHT)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Set `RESIZE_WIDTH` and `RESIZE_HEIGHT` to whichever value you need.

Add it as a `Run Shell Script` step:

[image]

and set `Shell` to `/use/bin/python` and `Pass input` to `as arguments`.

**EDIT**: there's a rather simpler way (suggested by [epatel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/842/epatel)) to achieve this, using `sips`.

You can create a `Run Shell Script` step with this command:

```
sips --resampleHeightWidth 100 100 "$@"
```

Note: Double Quotes need to surround $@ or you will get an error.

[image]

Comment: Could have used `sips` too, a command line tool available on OSX.

Comment: Thanks for this answer...really saved hours of my time.

Comment: Actually, it _is_ possible directly in Automator. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, use the "Crop Images" action and set the "Scale before crop", "Width" and "Height" options as desired. You might also find the "Pad Images" action helpful.

Comment: This exactly answers the question to my eyes and was the answer I was looking for! Thanks!